# Unable to make Smarty tag meaning

Tags: smarty

I have below code in smarty template. I am unable to interpret what paging does.  calc, total, current, per_page, url are variable but what is paging

```
{paging calc=$pInfo.calc total=$dealers|@count current=$pInfo.current per_page=$config.dealers_per_page url=$search_results_url}
```

Answer (score 1):

`{paging}` seems to be a custom Smarty plugin.

Answer (score 0):

as @Iko mentioned, {paging} is likely a smarty plugin
Check your smarty plugins folder for a file named 'functions.paging.php' - you should be able to find the php code that processes those parameters. If you're lucky that code might have links to documentation or the publisher if created by a third party.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.naming.conventions.tpl